# Will my mdadm reshape operation complete?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, mdadm, raid5

I was adding an additional new drive to 4 drive raid 5 mdadm array. During the process that new drive was marked as faulty, along with one of the original 4 working drives.

From looking at logs I see this error from the original drive failing (sde1), the new drive sdf1 is also on the same pci card. I wonder if maybe the problem is this card rather than the drives.

```
21:59:49 kernel: [ 4339.536403] sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] tag#29 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
```

Previously to this the array had been readable and not reporting an error with any of the 4 drives.

Current mdadm status the operation seems to be stalled, the speed is continually droppping

After removing the disks mdadm marked as failed (sde1 and sdf)

```
       Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Fri Jan 16 18:36:21 2015
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 8790406656 (8383.19 GiB 9001.38 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2930135552 (2794.40 GiB 3000.46 GB)
   Raid Devices : 5
  Total Devices : 3
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Mon Jan 15 21:25:18 2018
          State : clean, FAILED, reshaping
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

 Reshape Status : 0% complete
  Delta Devices : 1, (4->5)

           Name : :0  (local to host )
           UUID : 4d3400aa:55dc5281:293e9722:46ad27b5
         Events : 418999

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       3       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       -       0        0        3      removed
       -       0        0        4      removed
```

My question is, am I waiting for an unrecoverable array if this reshape completes?

Mdadm is attempting to grow a 4 disk array to a 5 disk array using 3 drives.... There should be enough parity data on 3 drives alone to recover my array, or will the process of growing that have already already ruined that?

This speed is continually dropping I'm not even sure if the process is still actively running

```
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10]
md0 : active raid5 sdd1[3] sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      8790406656 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [5/4] [UUU__]
      [>....................]  reshape =  0.2% (6104064/2930135552) finish=53459.5min speed=911K/sec
      bitmap: 2/22 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: My guess would be that it won't stop.  Sounds like you need to stop it manually and get another drive added back into it and try doing a recover back to your 4 drive system first before adding the 5th drive in that will go through the full reshaping and resize of the RAID.  Some commands that might be helpful:  https://vexatioustendencies.com/manually-starting-or-stopping-a-raid-check-in-linux/

Comment: Thanks you are correct I had to abort the process and I'm currently unable to build the array. I get nothing but kernel errors from both disk drives attached to the pci card when I try and mount the array, so I'm hoping that it's just the controller in the card that's died. No idea if it'll be recoverable once I try a new PCI controller in it at the moment though.

Comment: When you try to add back the fourth drive, make sure you add the option `--raid-devices=4` when you go to rebuild the data.  As it stands, it thinks there are 5 and if that follows through it will corrupt all the data because RAID 5 is only 1 drive fault tolerant.